# Проблемы с flex-box HTML + CSS

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка, flexbox

Есть блок с новостями. Хочу, чтобы после применения `align-items: flex-start;` блоки смещались к верху, как показано на фото №2, чтобы не было пробелов. У меня сейчас блоки с 2-й строки выравниваются по самому большому блоку из 1-й строки, а нужно, чтобы выравнивались автоматически по размерам верхнего блока. Пробовал через align-content - что-то не вышло.

```
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  display: flex;  
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

[image: Скрин №1 - То, что есть]

[image: Скрин №2 - То, что нужно]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Старый и добрый `column-count` который принимает не ограниченное количество высоты и который 100% поддерживается везде и сам пересчитывает

Вот здесь можно экран сужать/расширять: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/oNjxepx и увидить column-count с медиа запросами

Что бы изменить кол-во столбиков достаточно написать `column-count: number`

```css
.items {
  column-count: 3;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fafafa;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.item img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.item h4 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
    <h4>name family1</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quod at incidunt nisi debitis a!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200" alt="">
    <h4>name family1</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis, accusamus.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" alt="">
    <h4>name family1</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem nostrum voluptate eos repudiandae harum mollitia? Minima, libero dolorem?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x250" alt="">
    <h4>name family1</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x240" alt="">
    <h4>name family1</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Dignissimos dolorum omnis provident animi a nam ex similique! Eos, sunt id.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x320" alt="">
    <h4>name family1</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab necessitatibus voluptate ut odio quasi, aperiam quos.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
    <h4>name family1</h4>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe repellendus nemo impedit pariatur.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x120" alt="">
    <h4>name family1</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt sint a omnis aperiam distinctio.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x180" alt="">
    <h4>name family1</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus, totam!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="">
    <h4>name family1</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque hic blanditiis autem minima necessitatibus, quidem excepturi in quia ipsum iure?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
    <h4>name family1</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi, eligendi.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x270" alt="">
    <h4>name family1</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus quis quisquam ipsa perferendis nam hic cupiditate. Voluptate veniam quos repellat.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="">
    <h4>name family1</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem, earum?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x250" alt="">
    <h4>name family1</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum, ducimus quibusdam.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x120" alt="">
    <h4>name family1</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit cupiditate ipsam aut.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
    <h4>name family1</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A obcaecati sequi nihil fugit perspiciatis suscipit facere, iste libero eum? Explicabo dolore mollitia eum. Ipsum temporibus officia nostrum dolor delectus explicabo.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Sevastopol' даже если бы ты сделал на grid и column-count то у меня в загашнике есть ещё один метод

Answer (score 6):

Есть такая хорошая штука, называется `masonry`. Но сегодня можно воспользоваться и аналогом, это уже, например, `flex` или `grid`. Поддержка браузерами, если использовать плагин `masonry`, будет практически 100%. С `flex` дела обстоят чуть хуже. А если использовать `grid`, тогда будет совсем плохо. Из двух зол выбираем наименьшее, пример с использованием `flex`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #555;
}

div#masonry {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vw;
  font-size: 0;
}

div#masonry img {
  width: 33.3%;
  transition: .5s opacity;
}

div#masonry:hover img {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

div#masonry:hover img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

@supports not (flex-wrap: wrap) {
  div#masonry {
    display: block;
  }
  div#masonry img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="masonry">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1257110/pexels-photo-1257110.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1054974/pexels-photo-1054974.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2253879/pexels-photo-2253879.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1257099/pexels-photo-1257099.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1128318/pexels-photo-1128318.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/532508/pexels-photo-532508.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/834508/pexels-photo-834508.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/50692/brothers-family-siblings-boys-50692.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940">
</div>
```

Comment: когда решение найдено, то всё так просто кажется :) Выглядит эффектно!  css не мой конек. Поэтому  `@supports not (flex-wrap: wrap)` Это опечатка или это не селектор **:not** ?

Comment: это получается что у автора вопрос лента новостей будет из 8 статей - да ?

Comment: ну я взял добавил в  твой пример одну картинку и её в бок сместило а не вниз